# Years' ComboBox WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, combobox

I'm actually working on a Windows Phone 7 application that contains a few comboBox, in one of them "a years ComboBox".I want to insert a loop in that comboBox that should contain years from 1919 till the present year.How should i proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at the [Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). It contains a `DatePicker` bring up a looping/scrolling date/month/year selector, emulating the feel of the native applications. Since the source is available, you could use this as a starting point to create your own "year selector" from the components.

Comment: @MarTech - Make sure they're included in the project and their build action is set to `Content`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog from [Telerik](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/10-08-31/building_a_windows_phone_7_control_from_the_ground_up_-_part_one_-_the_infinite_listbox.aspx) on how to accomplish the looping effect.  Essentially it is just a list with a virtualized data source.

Comment: I found it a little complicated compared to @Richard Szalay's answer!